# Add a constant value to a cell on each iteration

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a fixed value (2 in this case) to a cell on each iteration?

I need to automatize the value of two cells (C1 and C2) to generate a receipt and print it.
The range is from 1 to 550 and the model has two receipts on it (1 and 2, 3 and 4...).

There is what i'm trying to do:

```
Sub print_pdf()

first = Range("R1").Value
'That is 1

last = Range("R2").Value
'That is 550

For i = first To last
            Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = i
            Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = i + 1
            
                file_name = Range("C1") & "-" & Range("C2") & ".pdf"
                ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=file_name

Next
Range("C1") = ""
Range("C2") = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Step 2` in for loop. Give a try on below sub-

```
Sub print_pdf()
    first = Range("R1").Value
    'That is 1
    
    last = Range("R2").Value
    'That is 550
    
        For i = first To last Step 2
            Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = i
            Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = i + 1
            Debug.Print i & "-" & i + 1
                'file_name = Range("C1") & "-" & Range("C2") & ".pdf"
                'ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=file_name
        Next
    Range("C1") = ""
    Range("C2") = ""
End Sub
```

Actually do not need to store file name in cell like `C1`, `C2`. Instead you can use variable directly to make a file name like-

```
file_name = i & "-" & i + 1 & ".pdf"
```